# What causes ld to not find the library here?

Tags: linux, path, libraries

I have got the `mpc` library (and others, but this is the example) installed in a custom directory:

```
user@host /my/software/prefix $ l usr/lib | grep mpc
lrwxrwxrwx  1 user group    15 Mar  5 21:08 libmpc.so -> libmpc.so.3.0.0
lrwxrwxrwx  1 user group    15 Mar  5 21:08 libmpc.so.3 -> libmpc.so.3.0.0
-rwxr-xr-x  1 user group   96K Mar  5 21:08 libmpc.so.3.0.0
```

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/21647591), I can get the location of a library from the linker flag (`-l<lib>`) doing something like:

```
ld -lmpc --verbose
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/my/software/prefix/usr/lib ld -lmpc --verbose
```

However, this turns up empty:

```
attempt to open /my/software/prefix/usr/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/lib64/libmpc.so failed
attempt to open /my/software/prefix/usr/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/lib64/libmpc.a failed
attempt to open /my/software/prefix/usr/lib/binutils/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/2.2464/libmpc.so failed
attempt to open /my/software/prefix/usr/lib/binutils/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/2.2464/libmpc.a failed
attempt to open /usr/local/lib64/libmpc.so failed
attempt to open /usr/local/lib64/libmpc.a failed
attempt to open /lib64/libmpc.so failed
attempt to open /lib64/libmpc.a failed
attempt to open /usr/lib64/libmpc.so failed
attempt to open /usr/lib64/libmpc.a failed
```

And it doesn't even search the path supplied by `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

What is going wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Put your /my/software/prefix/usr/lib in /etc/ld.so.conf and run sudo ldconfig.

Comment: `etc/ld.so.conf` is overwritten by `ldconfig` (I think this is the case for every system)

Comment: Strange, it is not overwritten in Slackware. This is how I have been adding library paths for the last 20 years and it's always worked for me. I just tried  it and it works fine. I even tried a non-existing path and it still works. Hmm. According to the ldconfig man page ldconfig reads the /etc/ld.so.conf to build the cache. There should be no overwriting of the ld.so conf file.